# mysql foreign key (Integrity constraint violation)

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, laravel-5.1

I'm working on a little support (ticket) system. My tables are tickets and ticket_replies.

Design of tickets table is

```
id|user_id|title|...
```

Design of ticket_replies looks like:

```
id|ticket_id|...
```

Now I would like to create a foreign key from the tickets table to the ticket_replies table. This foreign key should protect the ticket_replies table from being edited without editing the ticket table before. Like if for example the id of the ticket changes the ticket_id should be changed in "ticket_replies" too. If a ticket is deleted in tickets it should be deleted in "ticket_replies" too.

The foreign key I added looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tickets` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `sampleauth`.`ticket_replies`(`ticket_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Creating this foreign key is successful, but when I try to insert data like:

```
            $ticket = new Ticket;
            $ticket->user_id = $user->id;
            $ticket->title = $request->title;
            $ticket->status = 0;
            $ticket->department_id = $request->departments;
            $ticket->save();

            //create new ticket_replie
            $ticket_replie = new Ticket_replie;
            $ticket_replie->ticket_id = $ticket->id;
            $ticket_replie->user_id = $user->id;
            $ticket_replie->text = $request->question;
            $ticket_replie->save();
```

It fails saying :

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (sampleauth.tickets, CONSTRAINT
>   tickets_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES ticket_replies (ticket_id)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into tickets
>   (user_id, title, status, department_id, updated_at, created_at) values
>   (1, sasa, 0, 1, 2016-01-18 23:03:21, 2016-01-18 23:03:21))

I understand why this occurs (because when I create a new ticket Mysql checks if ticket_id from ticket_replies matches the ticket_id), but I have no idea how to solve this, any idea?

Comment: You should add the foreign key in ticket_replies table not in ticket table. 
Your parent table should be ticket table and the child table should be ticket_replies table.

Comment: I tried to do so, see below. Problem is all the time the error occurs as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those will work

```
ALTER TABLE `tickets` DROP FOREIGN KEY `ticket_ibfk_1`;
ALTER TABLE ticket_replies ADD FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Those are complete test code i ran.

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ticket_replies` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `reply` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE ticket_replies ADD FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES tickets(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

insert into tickets(name) values('123');
insert into ticket_replies(ticket_id, reply) values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'123');
```

Comment: This produces same error as described above (`Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:....`), see above.

Comment: oops copied your sql.
anyway i fixed it maybe later someone might need this.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping. Running your updated second command results in error `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint `.

Comment: working on my mysql 5.6. maybe some version difference?

Comment: I don't think so, I've added a index for the ticket_id on table ticket_replies. No I can add the foreign key, but when I try to add some values into database it results in same error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sampleauth`.`tickets`, CONSTRAINT `tickets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tickets` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `tickets` (`user_id`, `title`, `status`, `department_id`, `updated_at`, ...)`

Comment: so, i think you are missing ids. i added my complete test code. Would you pls check it.

Comment: I added a new thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871811/mysql-foreign-key-permissions], I think the problem I described above is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference ticket from *ticket_replies* to *ticket*.

This is common rule:

When you name column like **{table_name}_id** (ticket_replies.ticket_id), you need to reference it to **{table_name}.id** (ticket.id).

So, you need to drop existing foreign key and create new:

```
ALTER TABLE tickets DROP FOREIGN KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ticket_replies ADD FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: So what did I need to do to get this working? Don't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: edit
ALTER TABLE `test_proc`.`ticket` DROP FOREIGN KEY `ticket_ibfk_1`;

Comment: I've deleted the foreign key I set on tickets table, after this I tried to run `ALTER TABLE ticket_replies ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_ticket_replies_ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`, this results in error `#1072 - Key column 'fk_ticket_replies_ticket_id' doesn't exist in table `.