# mysql foreign key "permissions" on delete

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a little support (ticket) system. My tables are tickets and ticket_replies.

Design of tickets table is

```
id|user_id|title|...
```

Design of ticket_replies looks like:

```
id|ticket_id|...
```

The foreign key I added looks like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE `ticket_replies` ADDFOREIGN KEY (`ticket_id`)
 REFERENCES `sampleauth`.`tickets`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Now when I delete a "ticket" in the "ticket" table it gets deleted in "ticket_replies" too. The other way this doesn't work, all in all I would like this to work the other way too, so my database has all the time consistency. How to do so?

Comment: this cannot be done with foreign keys you have to add trigger or something to do that

Comment: using mutliple foreign keys won't solve this problem right?

Comment: yes won't, i think using trigger is best choice you have.

Answer (score 0):

Add this trigger will delete its primary key when you try to delete foreign key

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ticket_replies_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `ticket_replies` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tickets WHERE id = OLD.ticket_id;
END
```